# getting the import spring libraries wrong when creating a new project from a creted archetype

Tags: java, maven

i had created an archetype from an existing project with the command mvn archetype:create-from-project.
everything worked fine. 
i installed and deployed it too.
the problem exists when creating a new project from this archetype.
it converts every "framework" word with the artifactid of the created project.
for example if the artifactid is "**test**", i get this:

```
 import org.springtest.security.core.Authentication;
```

the reason is that in the created archetype files i found it written like this:

```
     import org.spring${artifactId}.security.core.Authentication;
```

My questions: is there a way or some files i should configure to stop replacing the "framework" word with the artifcatid ??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.
in the created archetype you will find the next lines written at the top of any java class:

```
   #set( $symbol_pound = '#' )
   #set( $symbol_dollar = '$' )
   #set( $symbol_escape = '\' )
```

so just add the following line to them.only once at any java class of the archetype.

```
   #set($artifactId = "framework")
```

note that you can do the same thing with groupid and package.